Building Rust/Tonic Streaming Server with Bazel
There are a lot of moving parts to this problem, so I created a GitHub repo just to illustrate it. Anybody feeling inclined to take a look can clone that repo to play around with it. The README has more information, but basically the first commit shows the broken behavior (with Bazel), and the second commit shows the working behavior (with Cargo).
I want to implement a Tonic gRPC service in Rust.
The "typical" way is to use tonic-build to generate server boilerplate using build.rs
and then include! it into src/lib.rs.
This works fine in the above-linked example repo (at the latest commit on main).
Something like this:
.
├── build.rs
├── Cargo.toml
├── foo.proto
└── src/
    └── lib.rs

// foo.proto
syntax = "proto3";

package foo;

service Foo {
    rpc Bar(Baz) returns (stream Baz) {}
}

message Baz {}

// src/lib.rs

use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio_stream::wrappers::ReceiverStream;
use tonic::{Request, Response, Status};

// Include the generated code from tonic-build.
// This is the only part that needs to be removed to work with Bazel.
pub mod foo_proto {
    pub mod foo {
        include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/foo.rs"));
    }
}

use foo_proto::foo::{foo_server::Foo, Baz};

struct FooServe {}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Foo for FooServe {

    // This is the part that's failing with Bazel
    type BarStream = ReceiverStream<Result<Baz, Status>>;

    async fn bar(&self, _request: Request<Baz>) -> Result<Response<Self::BarStream>, Status> {
        todo!()
    }
}

I need to use Bazel, though. So I add a MODULE.bazel file to bring in dependencies from crates.io, and a BUILD file to compile the same source. Pretty much everything actually works pretty well. Bazel can generate rust source code from the .proto file using Prost / Tonic, and it has all the correct methods / structures in there. You can see the generated Rust in bazel-out/, and I can import the modules into src/lib.rs. The only problem is this cryptic error I'm getting about the return type of the streaming method. Tokio's ReceiverStream implements Stream, but the rust compiler is somehow oblivious to that.
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ReceiverStream<Result<Baz, Status>>: futures_core::stream::Stream` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:19:22
   |
19 |     type BarStream = ReceiverStream<Result<Baz, Status>>;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `futures_core::stream::Stream` is not implemented for `ReceiverStream<Result<Baz, Status>>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `futures_core::stream::Stream`:
             &mut S
             AssertUnwindSafe<S>
             Box<S>
             Pin<P>
             Streaming<T>
             TcpIncoming
             axum::extract::request_parts::BodyStream
             futures_channel::mpsc::Receiver<T>
           and 109 others
note: required by a bound in `foo_proto::foo::foo_server::Foo::BarStream`
  --> bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/foo_proto.lib.rs:108:13

Would love if anybody could point me in the right direction. Would also appreciate feedback if the reproduction GitHub repo does not work as advertised for anybody.
I've tried adding all sorts of deps to the Bazel rule, but nothing works.

Please edit your question to include the relevant code and error messages. Simply adding a link to github is not enough.

How was your code working in the first commit even when foo_proto module was not present?

Added more details, but given how many different (small) files you need to reproduce it, it's hard to convey in a post.
@TimsibAdnap the module is present in the first commit of the GH repo. It's included somehow in the commands passed to rustc by Bazel, which also generates the Rust code, so build.rs is ignored and nothing gets included like how it works with tonic-build.

The only way that error makes sense is if tokio-stream's futures_core dependency is somehow different than the futures_core used in the injected foo_proto. But unfortunately I do not know enought about Bazel or how it works with Rust to investigate how that could be. Figuring out how to log the rustc commands would go a long way I think.

My bad. This was happening because I failed to read instructions on setting up a Prost toolchain. Setting one up solved the problem.
